# Is it possible to save Geometry Nodes modifier?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I would like to use created Geometry Nodes modifier in other projects and I can't find any way to save them.

Comment: Do you want it to be present in each new file you create or do you have it saved in one file and want to append it in a different one?

Comment: I think what I am looking for is the option to import previously created GeoNode modifier.

Or to transfer group of Nodes between files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two Options:

1.) Right-click the Geometry Nodes Modifier in the Outliner and **Mark as Asset**, so you can access it from *any other blend file* via the [Asset Browser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html)

[image]

2.) When you have *a specific blend file* already open, you can select **File > Append** in the main menu to insert your Node Tree into the open blend file: Double click on the blend file that contains your GeoNodes Setup and look into the folder named "NodeTree". (It may be a good idea to check "Fake User")

[image]

Comment: For some reason I don't have such folder as NodeTree. Unfortunately I can't reproduce those instructions.

Comment: The "append" function opens a file browser in which you can navigate **into** the internal directories of your blend file. It should be there.

Comment: Allright. Now I get it. I was looking for the file named as Geometry Nodes modifier. Where it have to be the file that Nodes where created in. 

Thanks.